# I am having a confusion in array object creation and assignment of it the new element

Tags: java

question: Can any one tell me why are we creating a new array object as array a1=new array(); and it is assigned as a value of 5.How is it put in the third index of an array. please provide a brief on it . As I am sort of Confused. Help!!! 
Cant we do a1[3]= new array();
then assign then assign a1[3].x="some integer";
Help me

```
class array
{ int x;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { //array a1=new array();
        array[] a;
        a = new array[4];
        a[0]=new array();
        a[1]=new array();
        a[2]=new array();
        a[3]=new array();

        a[0].x=2;
        a[1].x=4;

        array a1=new array();
        a1.x=5;
        a[3]=a1;
        System.out.println("the third array is" +a[3].x);



       // a[3].x=5;
        System.out.println("The first array object is "+a[0].x);






    }//End of the main//
}//end of the class/
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the name `array` for the class is very confusing here.

You are creating an array that contains objects of class `array`.

First you create an array with four elements :

`a = new array[4];`

and then, for each element of the array, you create an object of type `array` :

`a[0]=new array();`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do

```
a1[3]= new array()
```

because

```
a1
```

is not an Array of your class name 'array'
Look at declaration of a1

```
 array a1=new array();
```

Change your class name from array and confusion will go away.